# How to replace null values with above/below not null value on same column in Data-frame using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to replace Null or invalid values present in a column with the above or below nonnull value of the same column. For Example:-

```
Name|Place|row_count
a   |a1   |1
a   |a2   |2
a   |a2   |3
    |d1   |4
b   |a2   |5
c   |a2   |6
    |     |7
    |     |8
d   |c1   |9
```

In this case, I try to replace all the NULL values in the column "Name" 1st NULL will replace with 'a' & 2nd NULL will replace with 'c' and in column "Place" NULL replace with 'a2'.
When we try to replace the 8th cell NULL of 'Place' column then also replace with its sparse nonnull value 'a2'.
**Required Result:**
   If we select the 8th cell NULL of 'Place' column replacing then result will be

```
Name|Place|row_count
a   |a1   |1
a   |a2   |2
a   |a2   |3
    |d1   |4
b   |a2   |5
c   |a2   |6
    |     |7
    |a2   |8
d   |c1   |9
```

if we select the 4th cell NULL of 'Name' column for replace then result will be

```
Name|Place|row_count
a   |a1   |1
a   |a2   |2
a   |a2   |3
a   |d1   |4
b   |a2   |5
c   |a2   |6
    |     |7
    |     |8
d   |c1   |9
```

Answer (score 0):

`Windows` functions would come handy to solve the issue. For the sake of simplicity, I'm focusing on just `name` column. If previous row has `null`, I'm using next row value. You can change this order according to your need.Same approach needs to be done for other columns as well.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(("a", "a1", "1"),
  ("a", "a2", "2"),
  ("a", "a2", "3"),
  ("d1", null, "4"),
  ("b", "a2", "5"),
  ("c", "a2", "6"),
  (null, null, "7"),
  (null, null, "8"),
  ("d", "c1", "9")).toDF("name", "place", "row_count")

val window = Window.orderBy("row_count")
val lagNameWindowExpression = lag('name, 1).over(window)
val leadNameWindowExpression = lead('name, 1).over(window)

val nameConditionExpression = when($"name".isNull.and('previous_name_col.isNull), 'next_name_col)
  .when($"name".isNull.and('previous_name_col.isNotNull), 'previous_name_col).otherwise($"name")

df.select($"*", lagNameWindowExpression as 'previous_name_col, leadNameWindowExpression as 'next_name_col)
  .withColumn("name", nameConditionExpression).drop("previous_name_col", "next_name_col")
  .show(false)
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----+---------+
|name|place|row_count|
+----+-----+---------+
|a   |a1   |1        |
|a   |a2   |2        |
|a   |a2   |3        |
|d1  |null |4        |
|b   |a2   |5        |
|c   |a2   |6        |
|c   |null |7        |
|d   |null |8        |
|d   |c1   |9        |
+----+-----+---------+
```

Comment: If I want to replace particular null(only one selected null) of a column, not all null of a column then how to replace null with just above not null data.

Comment: how do you differentiate that particular null ?

Comment: From UI(client) can send the location.

Comment: Can it possible to use lag or lead anyone only to replace all null in a column.